# Joomla built-in registration form : Error is encountered after submitting the form

Tags: joomla

I'm a newbie in Joomla. And I have this issue re the built-in registration form I added as one of my menu item. After I filled out and submit the form, the page is displaying I guess, error. It's something like :

```
string(462) "03AGdBq24C4KJlippyd5b8xY4nEC0O0BBJhSWu3BYUKM_-IWHl_dYa6tsHSGx61...UUOY9CkztnEwjuv9PwWe3yUybyRdipEa1yrWbZBH9TmpOmqikB1awApyWjpbm9VgsGKLyxQy01B8YJV20Yqcfpk7RADNaRPb6SO4r-hjn" array(1) { [0]=> bool(true) }
```

I already set the Allow User Registration to Yes in Users: Options menu. Thank you

Comment: Which Joomla version do you use? Is it the most recent version (3.9.27 as of today) ? What happens if you directly access and use the registration form via /index.php?option=com_users&view=registration ?

Comment: Hi...I am currently using version 3.9.12...Also tried to directly access the registration form as you mentioned, i am getting the same results. I also tried to use the login module instead of menu item, same results as well

Comment: It's recommended to update your software to the latest version. If your issue was a bug, it might have been solved with any of the updates. Have you any non-core extensions installed (in particular: plugins) ? Have you tested it with Protostar, the Joomla default  template?

Comment: I installed j2store as i am currently doing an ecommerce website. I am also using shoplook template. Yes, I tried the Protostar template and i'm still getting the same issue. I'll try to update my software, hope it will work.

Comment: Re updating my joomla...when i go to admin control panel page, it says I already have the latest Joomla version, 3.9.12...thanks